# features of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

what are the most important features a web developer should know about in asp.net?
i am asking this question because i am a newbie and i want to learn c#, and i found a lot of books about: ajax,edmx,asmx,custom controls,jquery,wcf,silverlight......
so in what order should i learn them, and what is are the most important ones?

Answer (score 7):

Learn about:

- The page life cycle - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)
- User and customer controls - [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667)
- Learn how HTTP works - start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)
- Understand the difference between client side and server side code - start [here](http://www.virtualshowrooms.co.za/articlepage.php?cp=101)
- Learn about asp.net MVC - [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/whatisaspmvc)
- HTML, Javascript and CSS (for completeness)

Comment: +1 programmers should know the inner workings and differences of a ASP.net web form and MVC.

Comment: Good answer! Lot's of webform developers out there that really doesn't know about HTTP and client/server side difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you're a complete beginner I suggest you first take a look at these technologies:

- html
- css
- javascript/jQuery

Great starters for these can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/.

For getting into ASP.NET (Webforms) start with these tutorials: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/fundamentals.

Edit: from years of experience or when I teach classes the hardest thing to grasp for beginners seems to be *ViewState* and what harm it can do to your pages total size. Take a look at [Taking a Bite Out of ASP.NET ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972427.aspx) for getting a teaser of what it can cause harm.

Comment: +1 on the HTML. most C# forms developers who jump to ASP.Net usually have trouble making their pages efficient because they don't know the difference between a <span> from a <div>.

Answer (score 1):

> i am asking this question because i am a newbie and i want to learn c#

Thoroughly answering your question with the detailing this topic deserves is beyond the scope of this context. So I reocmmend to **Start from [Stage 1 here](http://www.asp.net/get-started)**.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that you should realize the main difference between developing a `client app` and a `web page`.

The web page is **stateless** and thus does not preserve the actual state.

It's just a request and a response (compared to the rich client preserving the states all the time - variables...)
When an ASP.NET page runs, the page goes through a life cycle in which it performs a series of processing steps.
You should read about it more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no particular order below is the one that I would follow:-

First understand the framework and how the applicaion or website communicates with the client.

Before anything else clear your basics of oops and have understanding of page life cycle.

Learn how to use controls on the tool box.

Learn basics of javascript.

Learn to make your own custom control.

Learn about ajax and actually understand not only using the already made tools.

Learn webservices and wcf.

And then by this time you will have clear picture of what you should learn next.

Answer (score 0):

You should also familiarize yourself with SQL Server since it's the most widely used database with .NET

Answer (score 0):

There are many new features available in asp.net4.5.  Below is the list of new features:

1. HTML Editor Features
2. Javascript Editor Features
3. Css Editor Features
4. The Page Inspector
5. Working with data
6. Framework Features
7. HTML5   features
8. Oauth and Security Features

For More Detail about above feature : http://rajeshprajapati.blogspot.in/2013/10/asp-net-45-features.html